# When I delete data from jquery data-table it still showing in grid until refresh

Tags: javascript, datatables

I tried that table automatically refresh but it does not until I manually reload the whole page.

When I delete data this exception occur in console on .draw();

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draw is not a function
>      at sortTableAfterdelete

```
function ConfirmDelteTraining(id) {

        $.post("/Franchise/deleteTraining", { TrainingId: id }, function (data) {

            if (data) {
                debugger;
                var t = $('#trainingGrid').DataTable();
                t.row($('#trainingGrid').find('[data-id=' + id + ']')).remove().draw();

                //Set order after deleting state
                sortTableAfterdelete();
         }

 function sortTableAfterdelete() {

        if ($("#trainingGrid tbody tr td").length == 1) {

            $('#trainingGrid').DataTable().search(this.value).draw();

        }
    };
```

Comment: in sortTableAfterdelete(), what is "this.value"? if this.value is undefined, search(undefined) may error out, and may not return a datatable instance. Therefore .draw is not a function. My question to you is, why do you need .search(this.value).draw()?

Comment: @Ji_in_coding yes it show undefined..I checked just by  $('#trainingGrid').DataTable().draw(); but this also show error.

Comment: the function sortTableAfterdelete() does not seem to be doing anything related to sorting. i think you just need to find a correct sorting example to apply to your code.

Comment: record is deleted but grid not refresh.

Answer (score 0):

remove .draw() and try.
draw will not come herer.

Comment: so where should I put??

Comment: why you are using it

Comment: I just want to refresh my grid automatically not to reload page manually.I there is alternate solution it would be nice.

Comment: use this to reload automatically  "location.reload()". no need to refresh grid

Comment: it reload all page

Comment: .draw(false); use true or false and check it

Comment: checked same issue